# polynomial ADT constructor and deletion

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a problem understanding how to use a constructor with the following class

```
class Polynomial{
private:
    typedef struct term{
        double coef;
        unsigned deg;
        struct term * next;
    }term_t;
    typedef struct term *Term;
    typedef struct term *Poly;
public:
    Polynomial(); //Constructor
    ~Polynomial(); //Destructor
    Poly newPoly(void);
```

How can i assign the constructor? And Poly newPoly(void) should return polynomial with no terms. I have trouble understanding how to use this specific struct in a polynomial for those functions.

Comment: Instead of having your own list of terms, why not use a standard container like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg because I have to do ADT of the polynomial

Comment: @JackF ADT has nothing to do with implementation, it's all about interface and behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `newPoly(void)`. That is just doing the work that a constructor should do.

Remove the typedefs they achieve nothing.

How you write you polynomial depends on how your class is designed, which you haven't told us. Normally for this kind of class you would define some member variables, which you would then initialize in the constructor. For instance you could write

```
class Polynomial{
private:
    struct term{
        double coef;
        unsigned deg;
        term* next;
    };
    term* head; // pointer to first term
    int size; // number of terms
public:
    Polynomial() { head = NULL; size = 0; }
    ~Polynomial();
};
```

But this is **only a suggestion**. It's up you to design this class, and to decide what member variables you need for that design.

Now to get a new polynomial with no terms, you would just write

```
int main()
{
    Polynomial p; // a new polynomial
    ...
}
```

Don't forget that you must also write a copy constructor and an assignment operator for this class.

Comment: I was given this typedef struct and I have to make it from low level ADT to high level ADT

Comment: thats why i am having trouble understanding the typedef struct, and i should be using it throughout the program lime void deletePoly(Poly *pP) and i am confused about that typedef struct

Comment: @JackF those typedefs are completely unnecessary in C++.

Comment: @JackF Just ignore the typedefs. You need the struct internally in the class however.

Comment: @john the typedefs especially at the end don't do anything?

Comment: They define type aliases, like typedef always does. I'm just saying they are unnecessary, not that they do nothing. If I were writing the code I would not use them. I suspect that your teacher is trying to demonstrate some obscure point and instead has just ended up confusing you.

Comment: @JackF No, they are type aliases, nothing to do with pointers. So within a Polynomial member function `Term` means the same thing as (i.e. is an alias for) `struct term *`. Similarly `Poly` also mens the same thing as `struct term *`. I had a feeling you didn't understand typedefs properly hence my advice to ignore them.